# How to select multiple items from a List view - JavaFX 8

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I'm new at using `JavaFX` and I'm trying to add an `ObservableList` to a table view.
The list contains only String.

My goals is to show list of connected devices and let the user choose on which to perform the action (1 or more), is there any better way to achieve this?

Edit:
Ive chaned to ListView and now it shows the list, how can I create a new list from the selected Items ?

Comment: Why not just a [ListView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html) ?

Comment: Also an option I just liked to look of the table view better, How can I select Items from the ListView ?

Comment: I think a single column table view will look a lot like a list.  You use listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() , or even better add a listener to the selectedItem property.  It's the same with TableView.

Comment: @brain thank you I have changed to List view and now it shows the ObservableList now Im didnt understand the listener part, how can I Create a new list from the selected Items ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example based on your comments

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ListSelect extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "one","two","three","four","five","six","seven");
        ListView<String> list = new ListView<>(items);
        ListView<String> selected = new ListView<>();
        HBox root = new HBox(list, selected);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        //set this to SINGLE to allow selecting just one item
        list.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        list.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs,ov,nv)->{
            selected.setItems(list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);}

}
```

Comment: Thank you I will check it when ill get home, where can I read about the listener , also what are thos parameters : (obs,ov,nv). and what does this meam : "->"

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html

Comment: Thank you will read I have also find this lambda explenation about the "->" expression : http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/lambda-expressions-in-java-8/240166764?pgno=2

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution that does not use Java's new Lamba and related features here it is:

In my example the assume the table was set up to work with an arbitrary class Person which defined a first name, last name and email.

```
//Set the table to multi selection mode
table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode( SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

//Regiseter the listener on the ObervableList<Person>
table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().addListener(multiSelection);


  /**A listener for list selections, multiple selections in the TableView**/
     ListChangeListener< Person> multiSelection = new ListChangeListener<Person>(){
        @Override
        public void onChanged(  ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Person> changed){
            for( Person p : changed.getList())
                System.out.println(p);
        } 
     };
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for