# Javafx listview set to multiple selection but still not working

Tags: listview, javafx

I don't really know what am doing wrong here. I set the selection mode for a listview to multiple selection mode, but I still can't make multiple selectiosn when I run the code.

This code launches the mainController class from the login window which has the list view

```
 try {
             Stage st = new Stage();
              FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));

             Parent sceneMain = loader.load();

             mainController controller = loader.<mainController>getController();
           

             Scene scene = new Scene(sceneMain);
             st.setScene(scene);
             st.setTitle("Window that contains the listView");
             
             st.getIcons().add(new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("icon.png")));
             st.show();
             
             ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();
             
             
         } catch (IOException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
```

below is the mainControler class

```
@FXML ListView<String> listViewReg;
@FXML ListView<String> listViewUnReg;

public void txtNumKeyRel(KeyEvent event){   
    
    if(txtRegNo.getText().length()==10){
            
            populateListViews();
            
            statusMessage("["+txtRegNo.getText().toUpperCase()+"]"+" details loaded", "success");
        }
        
    }   
}
```

the populate list method

```
public void populateListViews(){
    
    ObservableList<String> listViewRegitems = FXCollections.observableArrayList(regSub);
    
    listViewReg.setItems(listViewRegitems.sorted());
    listViewReg.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
            
    ObservableList<String> listViewUnRegItems= FXCollections.observableArrayList(unRegSub);
    
    listViewUnReg.setItems(listViewUnRegItems.sorted());
    listViewUnReg.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
    
    
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30607807/how-to-select-multiple-items-from-a-list-view-javafx-8

Comment: Thank you but what i mean is that after running the program i cant still select more than one cell in the listview

Comment: You need to post enough code that will duplicate your problem.

Comment: i have edited my post to include more code

Comment: If you look at the link I shared, you will see that there is a listener that does something with the selected items. You don't have that.

Comment: Where are you calling `populateListViews()`? Can you create a [MCVE] that other people can run (surely there is no need here for a database, multiple list views, etc, just to demonstrate this problem: get rid of everything that is not relevant and make the example complete).

Comment: Hope it now miniman @James_D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select multiple items from a List view - JavaFX 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30607807/how-to-select-multiple-items-from-a-list-view-javafx-8)